# How to add a text to the right side of `fa-circle-thin` class in html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a layout like the below image.I tried like the below code,but it's difficult to add an text to the right side of  `fa-circle-thin` class.How can I achieve it?

```css
.test {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left: 2px solid #b5b3b5;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin" style="font-size:24px;color:#b5b3b5; position: absolute;"></i>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin" style="font-size:24px;color:#b5b3b5; position: absolute;"></i>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin" style="font-size:24px;color:#b5b3b5; position: absolute;"></i>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use case for css pseudo-selectors. Take a look at this (updated) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unkLjrvk/23/) or snippet below and let me know if you have an specific questions.

```css
.modal-body{
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.circle-wrapper::after {
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 2px solid #b5b3b5;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 21px;
}

.circle-wrapper::before {
  height: 46px;
  border-left: 2px solid #b5b3b5;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: -44px;
}

.circle-wrapper:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.circle-wrapper:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
.modal-body .fa {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #b5b3b5;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-body .text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.inner-circle .fa {
   font-size: 16px;
}

.inner-circle {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}

.inner-circle::before {
  height: 22px;
  border-left: 1px solid #b5b3b5;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 2px;
}

.inner-circle:last-child::after {
  height: 18px;
  border-left: 1px solid #b5b3b5;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 36px;
}

.inner-circle:last-child {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.inner-contents {
  position: relative;
  top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="modal-body">
      <div class="circle-wrapper">
          <div class="outer-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
            <span class="text">Test code</span>
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle">
              <div class="inner-contents">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                  <span class="text">Test code inner</span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle">
              <div class="inner-contents">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                  <span class="text">Test code inner 2</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circle-wrapper">
        <div class="outer-circle">
              <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
              <span class="text">Test code 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle">
              <div class="inner-contents">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                  <span class="text">Test code inner</span>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle">
              <div class="inner-contents">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                  <span class="text">Test code inner 2</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circle-wrapper">
          <div class="outer-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
            <span class="text">Test code 3</span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much,this is working fine.but i couldn't create the inner loops.is it possible to add a div inside the fa classes?

Comment: What do you mean you can't create the inner loops? Do you only have access to modify some of the html, but not all?

Comment: No,i mean in the above image,there are another lines and texts(with time slots) inside the 'Process' and 'In Transit'.So if I need to create those,I need to create another div inside 'fa class',So here for the above code,how can I modify it and do it?

Comment: Please help on this issue

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle that matches your image above [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unkLjrvk/23/). The heights are currently hardcoded to fit 2 inner values for each outer one, but you can adjust accordingly depending on your content.

Comment: If I add more inner values,how to allow the circle-wrapper to increase it's height automatically? I tried some css elements like overflow,auto.but not working at all.

Comment: @temp, you can use javascript to apply a class corresponding to the amount of circles you have, and then update the height values accordingly for each class. If you know the amount of circles in advance, then you don't need js and just apply the right classes off bat.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit this code.........

```css
/* -------------------------------------
 * For horizontal version, set the
 * $vertical variable to false
 * ------------------------------------- */


/* -------------------------------------
 * General Style
 * ------------------------------------- */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans);
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #eee9dc;
  background: #48b379;
}

h2 {
  margin: 3em 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* -------------------------------------
 * timeline
 * ------------------------------------- */

#timeline {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 50px 0 30px 120px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-left: 8px solid #eee9dc;
}

#timeline li {
  margin: 40px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#timeline p {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.date {
  margin-top: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: -158px;
  font-size: 0.95em;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle {
  margin-top: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: -44px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #48b379;
  border: 5px solid #eee9dc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  max-height: 20px;
  padding: 50px 20px 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.content:before,
.content:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  right: 100%;
}

.content:before {
  border-right-color: inherit;
  border-width: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.content:after {
  border-right-color: #48b379;
  border-width: 17px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
}

.content p {
  max-height: 0;
  color: transparent;
  text-align: justify;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.radio {
  display: none;
}

.radio:checked+.relative label {
  cursor: auto;
  transform: translateX(42px);
}

.radio:checked+.relative .circle {
  background: #f98262;
}

.radio:checked~.content {
  max-height: 180px;
  border-color: #eee9dc;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transform: translateX(20px);
  transition: max-height 0.4s linear, border-color 0.5s linear, transform 0.2s linear;
}

.radio:checked~.content p {
  max-height: 200px;
  color: #eee9dc;
  transition: color 0.3s linear 0.3s;
}


/* -------------------------------------
 * mobile phones (vertical version only)
 * ------------------------------------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #timeline {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-left: none;
  }
  #timeline li {
    margin: 50px 0;
  }
  label {
    width: 85%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(18px);
  }
  .content {
    padding-top: 45px;
    border-color: #eee9dc;
  }
  .content:before,
  .content:after {
    border: solid transparent;
    bottom: 100%;
  }
  .content:before {
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
    border-width: 17px;
    top: -16px;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: -17px;
  }
  .content:after {
    border-bottom-color: #48b379;
    border-width: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: -20px;
  }
  .content p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
  .circle,
  .date {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>CSS3 Timeline</h2>

<ul id='timeline'>
  <li class='work'>
    <input class='radio' id='work5' name='works' type='radio' checked>
    <div class="relative">
      <label for='work5'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
      <span class='date'>12 May 2013</span>
      <span class='circle'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio ea necessitatibus quo velit natus cupiditate qui alias possimus ab praesentium nostrum quidem obcaecati nesciunt! Molestiae officiis voluptate excepturi rem veritatis eum aliquam qui laborum
        non ipsam ullam tempore reprehenderit illum eligendi cumque mollitia temporibus! Natus dicta qui est optio rerum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class='work'>
    <input class='radio' id='work4' name='works' type='radio'>
    <div class="relative">
      <label for='work4'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
      <span class='date'>11 May 2013</span>
      <span class='circle'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio ea necessitatibus quo velit natus cupiditate qui alias possimus ab praesentium nostrum quidem obcaecati nesciunt! Molestiae officiis voluptate excepturi rem veritatis eum aliquam qui laborum
        non ipsam ullam tempore reprehenderit illum eligendi cumque mollitia temporibus! Natus dicta qui est optio rerum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class='work'>
    <input class='radio' id='work3' name='works' type='radio'>
    <div class="relative">
      <label for='work3'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
      <span class='date'>10 May 2013</span>
      <span class='circle'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio ea necessitatibus quo velit natus cupiditate qui alias possimus ab praesentium nostrum quidem obcaecati nesciunt! Molestiae officiis voluptate excepturi rem veritatis eum aliquam qui laborum
        non ipsam ullam tempore reprehenderit illum eligendi cumque mollitia temporibus! Natus dicta qui est optio rerum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class='work'>
    <input class='radio' id='work2' name='works' type='radio'>
    <div class="relative">
      <label for='work2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
      <span class='date'>09 May 2013</span>
      <span class='circle'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio ea necessitatibus quo velit natus cupiditate qui alias possimus ab praesentium nostrum quidem obcaecati nesciunt! Molestiae officiis voluptate excepturi rem veritatis eum aliquam qui laborum
        non ipsam ullam tempore reprehenderit illum eligendi cumque mollitia temporibus! Natus dicta qui est optio rerum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class='work'>
    <input class='radio' id='work1' name='works' type='radio'>
    <div class="relative">
      <label for='work1'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</label>
      <span class='date'>08 May 2013</span>
      <span class='circle'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio ea necessitatibus quo velit natus cupiditate qui alias possimus ab praesentium nostrum quidem obcaecati nesciunt! Molestiae officiis voluptate excepturi rem veritatis eum aliquam qui laborum
        non ipsam ullam tempore reprehenderit illum eligendi cumque mollitia temporibus! Natus dicta qui est optio rerum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```